# How to ensure that a file has been changed in a pull request

Tags: git, gradle, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

Just a quick intro to the setup first:

So in our setup we use gradle and an artifactory for publishing new builds and getting dependencies, combined with jenkins for pipelines and git with bitbucket for source control. In our setup any pulls to master goes through a pull request in bitbucket, which has to pass the gates defined in the jenkinsfile and a review. Once these has passed the user can merge the request.

Because we have a setup where we have many git repos which can each be published seperately, it is imperative that the users remember to bump the semantic version correctly when they pull their changes to master (Since every build that runs on master, publishes the output of the build to the artifactory).
So to ensure that people remembers to update the semantic version I would like to either check that the gradle.properties file HAS changed compared to the point where the branch was created - But since we use shallow clones on our jenkins server there is no information about this. So normal "git diff" commands will not work. (My git-fu is not very strong but I have tried to google around and so far nothing has worked).

Another solution would maybe be a hook in bitbucket that rejects PR's which doesnt have any changes to the semantic version. But I havent found such a plugin yet.

A third option would be a githook that just bumps it when the branch is created, but I would like the user to be 100% aware that the version is bumped, since sometimes it is very important whether the major, minor or patch version has been increased. (And maybe this wouldnt work if people create the branch in jira/bitbucket...)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe it, but I have exactly the same setup :) Easiest solution for me was that I have jobs that publish to aritifactory (publishing stage), but before they do that they create a git tag (tagging stage) based on the version in gradle.properties. Now if that tag already exists, pushing it will fail. Let's say you have tag `v1234` and you do

`git tag v1234` - will work

`git push --tags` - will fail

 Also I notify bitbucket about the failed build, and then people can see that it happened because the git tag already exists meaning they didn't update the version

Comment: Ah nice :) I will try this when I get around to it. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Hi Mike, gonna go against myselft a bit now - that's good but you shouldn't accept the answer until it's correct and stuff actually works :) You can upvote initially, but accept only if you verifies that it's correct

Comment: Ill remember that :)

Comment: Been some time but I thought I would say what I ended up doing. Since we dont want to tag everything I couldnt use the tag solution. Ended up making a small ruby script that would just shallow clone the master of the current repo and then compare gradle.properties with the current one. This ruby script now has a stage of its own in the jenkins pipeline and so it will be impossible to get a job to succeed without having the version updated.